# Making list control read only in IBM Anywhere

Tags: javascript, maximo-anywhere

I am calling an eventHandler on a list control in app.xml on render event.
The eventHandler calls the method correctly. I want to make the list readonly depending upon flag value.

```
readOnly : function(eventContext)
{
   if (flag==true)
      eventContext.setDisplay(true); 
   else
       eventContext.setDisplay(false);
}
```

setDisplay method makes the list visible/non-visible depending upon flag value.
What is the correct way to make the list control read only?

Answer (score 0):

You get the metadata for the field, then set the property on that particular field.

```
//get the current record: 
var currWO = eventContext.getResource().getCurrentRecord();
//set the readonly attribute to true. 
currWO.getRuntimeFieldMetadata('fieldname').set('readonly'), true;
```